# Save Null value in SQL Server via Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table in which I need to insert **Null** value. Inside "**FamilyTreeMember**" table I have a column called "**BirthMonth_Id**" which is a FK to another table called **BirthMonthDD**. BirthMonthDD is my lookup table which I use it to generate DropDownList items.

In my current setup, I need to allow the end user to leave that field blank and save it as Null but it doesn't happen that way and instead it returns the old/same value. I don't get any error message. I can easily update the value from one thing to another. Example from February to August and ...

How can I fix this?

### Model

```
public class FamilyTreeMember
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public Guid FamilyTreeMemberId { get; set; }

        public int? BirthDay { get; set; }
        public virtual MonthDD BirthMonth { get; set; }
        public int? BirthYear { get; set; }
        public bool DOBEstimated { get; set; }       
    }
```

### ViewModel

```
public class EditFamilyTreeMemberViewModel
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string CaseId { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string FamilyTreeMemberId { get; set; }


        [UIHint("Day")]
        [RegularExpression(@"([0-9]+)", ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be a number.")]
        [Display(Name = "Day Of Birth")]
        public int? BirthDay { get; set; }

        [UIHint("ComboBox")]
        [AdditionalMetadata("BindTo", "months")]
        [Display(Name = "Month Of Birth")]
        public int? BirthMonth { get; set; }


        [UIHint("Year")]
        [RegularExpression(@"([0-9]+)", ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be a number.")]
        [Display(Name = "Year Of Birth")]
        public int? BirthYear { get; set; }

        [UIHint("Bool")]
        [Display(Name = "DOB Estimated")]
        public bool DOBEstimated { get; set; }
    }
```

### Controller (Update method)

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(EditFamilyTreeMemberViewModel editfamilytreemember, Guid? ftm, Guid? cid, Guid? mid)
{
    ViewBag.ftm = ftm;
    ViewBag.cid = cid;
    ViewBag.mid = mid;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (ftm == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        using (db)
        {
            var ftmember = await db.FamilyTreeMember.SingleOrDefaultAsync(z => z.FamilyTreeMemberId == ftm);

            ftmember.BirthDay = editfamilytreemember.BirthDay;
            ftmember.BirthMonth = await db.MonthDD.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == editfamilytreemember.BirthMonth);
            ftmember.BirthYear = editfamilytreemember.BirthYear;
            ftmember.DOBEstimated = editfamilytreemember.DOBEstimated;

            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "FamilyTree", new { cid, mid });
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Use `ftmember.BirthMonth_Id = editfamilytreemember.BirthMonth;` and you data model should have a property `public MonthDD int BirthMonth_Id  { get; set; }`

Comment: Can and should the Birthday component be `null`? That's the question you've got to ask yourself. You would want to try and reduce the amount of `null`s you are using.... Try looking at the null object pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can't break a relationship that has not been loaded before. So either `Include` the relationship when you query for your member:

```
var ftmember = await db.FamilyTreeMember.Include(x => x.BirthMonth).SingleOrDefaultAsync(z => z.FamilyTreeMemberId == ftm);
```

Or load this relationship before you set it to `null`:

```
db.Entry(ftmember).Reference(x => x.BirthMonth).Load();
```

This problem arises becase the property is `null` before you assign it (since the relationship hasn't been loaded), so when you assign `null` to it, it doesn't mark it as modified.

Comment: Thanks, I started by using the last part of your question and I get the following error:"The property 'BirthMonth' from the property path 'BirthMonth' is not a complex property on type 'FamilyTreeMember'. Property paths must be composed of complex properties for all except the final property."

Comment: @NoMore_CodeMaster ouch, that is right, that won't work for references... you'd need to find the mapping (and that's getting into the `ObjectContext` context which I don't recommend). See my update (using `Reference` and `IsLoaded` instead of `Property` and `IsModified`): again, untested, it may not work at all

Comment: I tried this one: db.Entry(ftmember).Reference(x => x.BirthMonth).Load(); and it worked, I'll also try the first one as well. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Yeah, loading should work... the last method just avoids the loading from the database if you don't need it (would save a more expensive query in the case of `Include` and a database roundtrip in the case of `Load`). The last untested method aims at "cheating" entity framework to avoid those... but if that doesn't work (again, haven't tested), then it's unavoidable in a simple manner

Comment: Ok, the first two solutions work well, which one do think is better to use?

Comment: The first one (`Include`) does the loading in just one query, the second one (`Load`) will hit the database twice, so I'd say the first one is the way to go. Try the updated third suggestion: if it works (which I don't know), it'll be the best

Comment: I added a fourth possibility... both #3 and #4 are untested, but if any works, would be better than #1 or #2

Comment: I tried your 3rd updated solution, this time it doesn't  have any error, it updates the value but not to Null.

Comment: Yeah, was a wild shot, I would have tested them, but I don't have an environment handy to do so... try #4, if it doesn't work, then stick with #1 or #2 :-)

Comment: I tried the #4, it seems there is no IsModified?
db.Entry(ftmember).IsModified = true;

Comment: I see, probably mistook an old version of EF... I'll remove those suggestions, sorry to get you try them :-)

Comment: No, not at all. It's good to see all kind of solutions. I will stick to "Include" since it's lot cleaner.